# How to add antd or chackraUI in my design system?

Tags: reactjs, antd, chakra-ui

I'm implementing a design system to publish on npm, for that I need to install Ant design or Chakra UI inside it, but when I try to install the design system it doesn't work. As I don't have Index.js to do the initial configuration of the libs in my design system, how can I make it work? I'm using Rollup.config technique to create design system.

Here is my project that will be published. I also accept suggestion of documentation for studies.

https://github.com/brunowbbs/wbsdesign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean you can't configure ant/chakra because you cant access them through the lib.

You could just export everything in the lib in your [index file](https://github.com/brunowbbs/wbsdesign/tree/master/src)

```
export * from "antd"
```

Note that if your lib has exports of the same name (probably does because button is ubiquitous) you might need to instead export each thing you need individually (a bit painful, but also correct).

```
export { THINGS YOU NEED HERE } from "antd"
```

I think you can also namespace it like this

```
export * as Antd from 'antd'
```

And use it like

```
import { Antd } from 'your-lib'

// <Antd.TheComponentYouWant >/
```

But this exposes antd naming externally so I'd prefer the former.

Comment: I don't want to export an element directly from antd, I'll need to do some combination of them with html elements to export a custom component.

Comment: What you have looks ok for that. What happens when you try importing Button for example from your libary?

Comment: With antdesign it worked. I believe it must be something css that was breaking.

And so that I can customize my components with chakra UI, how can I do its initial configuration, since I need to add a provider in the initial file?

Comment: <ChakraProvider>
      <TheRestOfYourApplication />
    </ChakraProvider>

Comment: Right gotcha. You would have to reexport the `ChakraProvider` from your index file, then in your app, youd import this from your library instead of chakra directly. Basically as above, but limited only to this provider component. You could also rename it before exporting in your lib if you wanted.

Comment: `export { ChakraProvider } from "@chakra-ui/react"` in your library index and then `import { ChakraProvider } from 'wbdesign'` in your app